# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer Error while using inject

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
[1,2,2,3].each.inject({}){|hash,e|
    hash[e.to_s]||=0
    hash[e.to_s]+=1
}
```

It returns

```
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer.
```

Comment: why this each in the middle and not directly the inject?

Comment: because i saw in Ruby doc , enum#inject ... so i tot inject for enum only ...

Comment: it's not vanilla Ruby, but consider using Facets, it's a cool library: http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#frequency-method. [1,2,2,3].frequency # => {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, consider using `group_by` and `count` instead:

```
arr = [1,2,2,3]
throwaway_hash = arr.group_by{|x| x}
result_hash = Hash[throwaway_hash.map{|value, values| [value, values.count]}]
# => {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

Answer (score 7):

The return value of the block is used as the *memo* object in the next cycle, so you just need to make sure the block returns `hash`.

```
[1,2,2,3].inject({}) do |hash,e|
  hash[e.to_s] ||= 0
  hash[e.to_s] += 1
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 1.9 you can use `each_with_object` instead of `inject` (note the reversed parameter order):

```
[1,2,2,3].each_with_object({}) do |e, hash|
  hash[e.to_s]||=0
  hash[e.to_s]+=1
end 
#=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>2, "3"=>1}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it is quite common to use the default hash value `Hash.new(..)`.

```
[1,2,2,3].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|e, hash| hash[e.to_s]+=1}
```